# SQL- how to store multiple id of table B into table A?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I'm a student and learning SQL.
I have table Student and table Subjects

```
-Student(ID,name,subjects)
(1,testing,here is the id of multiple subject)

-Subjects (ID,name,Desc)
(1,Subject1,somedesc)
(2,Subject2,somedesc)
(3,Subject3,somedesc)
(4,Subject4,somedesc)
```

so I want to store the multiple entry of subjects into 1 entry of student.
any idea how can I make it? If not possible, what would you recommend?

Comment: You need to create 3rd table which stores Student table id and subject Id. it is many to many relationship.  ex. stud_sub(ID, stud_id,sub_id).

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend your current approach, because you are trying to store comma separated, unnormalized, data in the `Student` table, where there is one record with a CSV list of subjects.  If someone were to give you an exact answer using this design, the query would be fairly ugly, and inefficient.  Instead, I recommend the following schema:

```
Student (ID, name)    -- and maybe other student metadata
Subjects (ID, name, description)
Student_Subjects (ID, StudentID, SubjectID)
```

Here, we store the relationship between one student and his subjects using multiple *rows* in the table `Student_Subjects`.  By the way, `Student_Subjects` is often called a "junction" or "bridge" table, because it connects two types of a data, in a clean and normalized way.

Now, if you want to persist a given student's subjects, you can use a single insert, something like:

```
INSERT INTO Student_Subjects (StudentID, SubjectID)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (1, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Foreign key constraint. In your example, consider `Student` as parent table and `Subjects` as child table.

```
Student (id, name)
Subjects (id, student_id, name, desc)
```

The foreign key of `Student` table referring the subjects is, student_id column in `Subjects` table.